# directive to rotate a div with angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

i am tryin to make a directive with angular, to rotate a div infinite. Let's say i got this html

```
<div class="card" pendulum></div>
```

i created a directive like this to change the rotation

```
pdany.directive('pendulum', function() {
        return function(scope, elem, attr) {
            elem.css({
                    '-moz-transform': 'rotate(90deg)',
                    '-webkit-transform': 'rotate(90deg)',
                    '-o-transform': 'rotate(90deg)',
                    '-ms-transform': 'rotate(90deg)'
                });
        }
    });
```

but this directive changes the rotation css and that's it, but now i try to add a timer inside the directive but i have no idea how to do that. Is there a way to make it work only in directive, or i have to add something in controller too? Thank you for help, Daniel!

Answer (score 3):

Without knowing how you want the element to rotate i can only suggest the following.

```
pdany.directive('pendulum', function() {
    return function($scope, $element, $attributes) {
       var degrees = 360;

       $element.css('transition', '-webkit-transform 800ms ease');

       var rotate = function() {
          $element.css('-webkit-transform', 'rotate(' + degrees + 'deg)');
          degrees += 360;
          setTimeout(rotate, 1000);
       };

        rotate();
    }
});
```

**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/kWvp6/3/**

Answer (score 2):

You should use css3 animations.

For example you should have in your stylesheet

```
@-webkit-keyframes rotate360{
    from {
        -webkit-transform:rotate(0deg);
    }
    to {
        -webkit-transform:rotate(360deg);
    }
}
@-moz-keyframes rotate360{
    from {
        -moz-transform:rotate(0deg);
    }
    to {
        -moz-transform:rotate(360deg);
    }
}
@-ms-keyframes rotate360{
    from {
        -ms-transform:rotate(0deg);
    }
    to {
        -ms-transform:rotate(360deg);
    }
}
@-o-keyframes rotate360{
    from {
        -o-transform:rotate(0deg);
    }
    to {
        -o-transform:rotate(360deg);
    }
}
@keyframes rotate360{
    from {
        transform:rotate(0deg);
    }
    to {
        transform:rotate(360deg);
    }
}
```

and in your elem.css

```
elem.css({
    'animation':'rotate360 1s linear 0s infinite',
    '-webkit-animation':'rotate360 1s linear 0s infinite',
    '-moz-animation':'rotate360 1s linear 0s infinite',
    '-ms-animation':'rotate360 1s linear 0s infinite',
    '-o-animation':'rotate360 1s linear 0s infinite'
});
```

Comment: well i want to improve my code and add a pendulum movement, that's why i need js to handle the movement, so i can add more complex movement patterns

Comment: Have you tried the animation-direction property with value **alternate** ?
more info here: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-direction